# Value Encryption using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding (Java code to PHP)

Tags: java, php, aes

I have been given sample code in Java and I have to write a code in PHP.
Output of PHP Code is not matching with Java Sample Output given.
The sample Java code may not be complete (it is what is given in the API documentation given to us. But in essential it summarizes the steps that we need to complete)

Message to encrypt is 
**4NPMCXGERGXSBI7F9IPM5000004NPMCXGERGXSBI7F9IPM**

**JAVA Code**

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;</br>
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;</br>
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;</br>
import io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest;</br>
class AAAA{  // class can have any name</br>
public static String getEncryptedTextFor(String text)</br>
    throws Exception {</br>
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");</br>
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];</br>
    String key = "YASHSHAH!@#987MOBAPP";</br>
    byte[] b = key.getBytes("UTF-8");</br>
    int len = b.length;</br>
    if (len > keyBytes.length) len = keyBytes.length;</br>
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);</br>
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");</br>
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);</br>
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);</br>
    byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));</br>
    return HttpRequest.Base64.encodeBytes(results);</br>
    }</br>
    }</br>
```

**PHP Code that we tried**

```
    $keyBytes = [];  
    $reqArrLen = 16;  
    $secretKey = 'YASHSHAH!@#987MOBAPP';  
    $a = utf8_encode($secretKey);  
    $b = unpack('C*', $a);   
    $len = count($b);  
    if($len > $reqArrLen){
    $len = $reqArrLen;
    }
    foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
    if($key <= $len)
    $keyBytes[]=$value;
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    $strtobyt = implode(array_map("chr", $keyBytes));
    $enLoan_Amount = AesCipher::encrypt($strtobyt, $eLoan_Amount);
```

Sample Output FORMAT in Java is : (This is not the actual output but format is shared)
    pnehvlPu2gKJXJabR+HbMERdHWnrdc713/SAsHOFWDQ9kv/eWNFI4IRmYWQ6QcoH

```
I'm not able to get this output format after executing PHP code.
```

Sample PHP Output :

2438bf468c0142c82127d1dd740f53c3c19125f724265d58811322b50027a876a05b35f61a767fced426597d09f592f3

PHP output length is 128 whereas Java is in 64.

Comment: You're not generating any output in your php code. So it's not possible to be the same as in java.

Comment: output in php code is $enLoan_Amount

Comment: You're not base64 encoding the php output (and you haven't shown the php output in your question)

Comment: php output is base64encoded. even if I write base64encode($enLoan_Amount), out out is same as the one which is printed above..
I have not written the php output as it not at all matching Java sample..

Comment: @Erwin Have added sample php output

Comment: You've changed the key from `HDFCBANK!@#987MOBAPP` to `YASHSHAH!@#987MOBAPP`. Thus, you should also post the corresponding Java output. Otherwise, your posted data aren't consistent. Moreover, which PHP-class `AesCipher` do you use? Currently, it's not possible to reproduce your PHP-
result.